# Is there any way in javascript for setting different color on button for different text value

Tags: javascript

Only those button have same color which have same test value like github tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it is possible. But where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) _"Please give me code"_ isn't the way this site works. Look at [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should first try yourself and should share your code what you have tried while asking question.**

Get all buttons, compare there text values and set background colors.

```
function changeButtonsBgColors() {
            var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
            for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                var button = buttons[i];
                if (button.value == "Close") button.style.background = '#C0C0C0';
                else if (button.value == "Ok") button.style.background = '#33FF3F';
                else if (button.value == "Done") button.style.background = '#4AC91B';
                else if (button.value == "Delete") button.style.background = '#FF0000';
            }
}
```

Just remember to have this code either in `onload` event or at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly doable. Assuming you're using jquery, it'll look something like this:

```
var bttnText = $('.button-class').html();
if(bttnText == 'some text'){
    $('.button-class').addClass('some-class');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery, try this: It will take any label you have with a class color-text and give it a random color, if it matches the text of another label then it will use the same color. Here is a jsfiddle link to see how it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/jamiguel77/atg5m6ym/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = [];
    $(".color-text").each(function(key,value){  
    if(colors[$(value).text()]) {
      $(value).css('color', colors[$(this).text()]);
    } else {
      var color = getRandomColor();
      $(value).css('color', color);
      colors[$(value).text()] = color;
    }
  });
});

function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```